# two dimensional string[] convert to string and output = matrix

Tags: java, char

I have written the code:

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Type your text: ");
    String text = input.nextLine();

    int counter = text.length();
    if(text.length()> 16)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: input text is greater than 16 characters");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        while(counter < 16)
        {
            text = text.concat("x");
            counter++;
        }

        char[][] k = new char[4][4];

        int push = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < k.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < k[i].length; j++)
            {
                k[i][j] = text.charAt(j+ push);
                System.out.print(k[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            push = push + 4;
        }
    }
}
```

And input is: **abcdefghijklm**

output is:

```
a b c d
e f g h
i j k l
m x x x
```

So all i want is, if i type: **abcdefghijklm**
I want this output:

```
a e i m
b f j x
c g k x
d h l x
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

To get your desired output, you're going to need to print out the matrix after populating it (you're also going to have to loop through it in a different way). Right now, you're adding each character to the matrix and immediately printing it, so you will print it in the same order as the input string (with extra line breaks).

So you want something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < k[i].length; j++) {
        k[i][j] = text.charAt(j+ push);
    }
    push = push + 4;
}

for(int i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < k[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(k[j][i]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: To be more specific, you can take the print statements out of the loops, then create another nested loop where you use something like `System.out.print(k[j][i] + " ");` (note the reversed indices).

Comment: hmmm, i don't understund? Have test this?

Comment: added some code to the response

Comment: this have sense, but i'm limited, i should use just two loops :s !!

Comment: you could use mod arithmetic to avoid using the nested loops

Comment: look bro this is okej, thank you. But now i want to print in this way:

a e i m, b f j x, c g k x, d h l x

Answer (score 1):

You simply need a `transpose` operation for your matrix. Just use two nested loops, and switch the indices. i.e. instead of `k[i][j]`, use `k[j][i]`.

Comment: And the output is: 

a

 b f 

 c g k

 d h l m

Comment: You need to take the print statement out of the loop. Ken's answer already elaborates this :-)